# Client unable to connect to server websocket using gevent-websocket

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, gevent

I am trying to stream data from a background server application to a client-side web-page using gevent-websocket.

When using localhost or leaving ('',8999) I am able to connect to the web-socket, but when trying to access from off the server I cannot seem to connect with the error `'Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://SERVER-IP:8999/.'`

I have tried other browsers with the same issue (well I tried chrome as well)

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    ws = environ['wsgi.websocket']
    stream_listener.add_socket(ws)
    while not ws.closed:
        gevent.sleep(0.1)

server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(
    ('0.0.0.0', 8999), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

As I said I have tried leaving it blank - putting in `'0.0.0.0'` in hopes that would bind it to all interfaces, but still no luck.

Here is the client side script that works from `localhost` - but trying to put in the `SERVER-IP:8999` fails.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://SERVER-IP:8999/");
ws.onopen = function() {
    ws.send("Hello, world")
}, ws.onmessage = function(a) {
    var b = JSON.parse(a.data);
    //do something with b
};
```

Comment: Explicitly specifying `127.0.0.1` means you're _asking_ to listen only for connections from localhost. So, you definitely don't want that, and it's just making the question misleading. If you've really tried it with `0.0.0.0`, then show _that_ in your example, and remove all the stuff about `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Added the 0.0.0.0 - and yes I did try this.

Comment: Yeah, I got that you tried `0.0.0.0` from reading carefully… but I almost went and started an answer explaining why `127.0.0.1` didn't work before I re-read it, and someone else might write that answer (or even just downvote you inappropriately). It's better to just include the code that _should_ work but doesn't than something else you tried that shouldn't have worked in the first place, just from a "getting good answers efficiently" point of view.